# Combined arrays and index out range issues in Swift array chunking problem

Tags: swift

I am trying to chunk a given array as per pre-determined `size`, I know there are other solution to the same problem but I wanted mine to be a little simpler.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation

let numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

var size = 2
var offset = size
var index = 0
while (index < (numbers.count) - 1)
{
    var slicedArray = numbers[index...(size - 1)]
    print(slicedArray)
    let arrayOfInts = Array(slicedArray)
    print(arrayOfInts)
    index = index + offset 
    size = size + size
}
```

Desired output:

```
//[2, 3]
//[4, 5]
 ...
```

Actual output:

```
//[2, 3]
//[4, 5]
//[6, 7, 8, 9]
//[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
//Fatal error: Array index is out of range
```

I know for sure this is logical error but unable to pin-point the exact reason. Also unable to understand as to why output arrays are being combined:

```
`[6, 7, 8, 9]` instead of `[6,7]` & `[8,9]`
```

Comment: This looks very suspicious: `size = size + size`

Comment: Should do size = size + offset, not multiply size by 2 each time.

Comment: Once again I observe that *debugging* is a dying art. Adding `print(index, size)` to the loop body would reveal the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `stride` to divide your array into chunks.

For convenience you can use the extension proposed [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks):

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

let numbers = Array(2...20)
let result = numbers.chunked(into: 2)

print(result)
// [[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler:

```
let numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

var size = 2
let offset = size
var index = 0
while (index < (numbers.count) - 1) {
    let slicedArray = numbers[index...index+1]
    let arrayOfInts = Array(slicedArray)
    print(arrayOfInts)
    index = index + offset
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion took out the major issue that I was facing. I have done some changes so that it can work all `size`. `let slicedArray = numbers[index...index + offset]` and `index = (index+1)+ offset`. Also getting `index` out of range when `size` is `4` or higher. Shouldn't `while` exit the moment `index` gets out of range?

Comment: Just compute an upperLimit : 
while (index < numbers.count - 1) {
    let upperLimit = min(index+offset-1, numbers.count - 1);
    let slicedArray = numbers[index...upperLimit];   With a size of 4 you'll get [2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20]